# How to parse HTML using the lxml.html library

Tags: python, lxml.html

Here is the `HTML` that appears on my site:

```
<meta content="auth" name="param" />
<meta content="I_WANT_THIS" name="token" />
```

How can I use [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) to grab that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to find the `meta` tag by `name` attribute and get the value of `content` attribute:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring


html_data = """ <meta content="auth" name="param" />
 <meta content="I_WANT_THIS" name="token" />"""

tree = fromstring(html_data)
print tree.xpath('//meta[@name="token"]/@content')
```

prints:

```
['I_WANT_THIS']
```

Comment: Can you explain what ".//meta[@name="token"]/@content'" does?

Comment: @user3412816 yup, it is an xpath expression that basically says: find me `meta` tag anywhere in the html, this meta tag show have an attribute `name` with the value `token`, then give me the value of `content` attrubite.